# function variable undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the top version not work and the lower function works? Learning about how to create and use objects and this baffles me. I assume it has to do with the fact I am using an object in the top part?

```js
var slot1 = {
  coffee: '1',
  tea: '2',
  espresso: '3'
}

function findItem( obj, prop ){
  var item = obj + '.' + prop;
  console.log(item);
}
findItem( slot1, coffee );


function addNumbs(num1,num2){
 var answer = num1+num2;
  console.log(answer);
}
addNumbs(4,3);
```

Right when I think I am getting the hang of it I get completely slapped in the face!

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading a JavaScript tutorial: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html . There are quite a few things wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for the read @FelixKling! I need more stuff like this... Any other newbie reads would be awesome btw ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that coffee is not defined in any scope as a variable, you can use the notation of obj['coffee']  passing coffee as a string in order for this to work. Or you can call it as slot1.coffee in order for you to get to it.

Answer (score 2):

The upper version does not work because of these two lines

`var item = obj + '.' + prop;`  & `findItem( slot1, coffee );`

When retrieving an object `a.b` or `a['b']` is enough where a is the object and b is key

Doing a +'.'+b  will result in concatenation ,instead of retrieving the value.

In function pass `coffee` as string otherwise it will pass as undefined value because it will presume coffee is declared somewhere which is not

Make this change

```
var slot1 = {
  coffee: '1',
  tea: '2',
  espresso: '3'
}

function findItem( obj, prop ){
  var item = obj[prop];
  document.write('<pre>'+item+'</pre>')
}
findItem( slot1,'coffee' );
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/evxw9q73/3/)

Comment: Oh, okay... I get that. I was watching a tutorial though and they returned values from an object like slot1 by using dot syntax... like slot1.coffee returned 1. is the correct way to return a property by slot1['coffee']?? Apologies for the nub-ness :\

Comment: @user1607991: `foo.bar` is equivalent to `foo['bar']`. You can use both.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use slot1.coffee instead of coffee

```
findItem( slot1, slot1.coffee );
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have property name in a variable use object like an array `myObject[property]` where property is a variable which contains a name of property of object you wanna get the value of.

Also, `coffee` is not to be used as variable but a string `"coffee"` or `'coffee'`

```js
var slot1 = {
  coffee: '1',
  tea: '2',
  espresso: '3'
}

function findItem( obj, prop ){
  var item = obj[prop]; // You need to access object property as if object was an array when you have property name in variable.
  console.log(item);
}
findItem( slot1, 'coffee' ); // You need coffee as a string here, variable coffee was never defined


function addNumbs(num1,num2){
 var answer = num1+num2;
  console.log(answer);
}
addNumbs(4,3);
```

Comment: Okay, so the lower num2 worked because 3 is a number and it knew it wasn't a variable...  I thought you could put whatever in the parenthesis and it treated it like declaring an empty variable (if that makes sense). thanks

Comment: Well... numbers can be declared lust like that- type in 25 and js will know it 25 an integer... but with strings you need to have them in quotes else it will conflict with variable names... like in you example, `slot1` is a variable containing an object, but `'slot1'` would be a string.

Comment: When you type in `coffee` it tries to find for variable named `coffee` but it can't find it anywhere hence the error. However when you type `'coffee'` it knows you are talking about a string saying coffee.